# Simple Perl Syntax Explanation

Tags: perl

I'm trying to translate a function from Perl which I've never programmed in to Java. I understand the code except for this line.

```
srand(time() ^($$ + ($$ <<15))) ;
```

I believe that srand is like Random.nextInt() in Java but I have no clue what $$ + $$ means in Perl nor the $$ << 15. I'm sure this is probably simple Perl syntax but I can't find a simple explanation.

Line in context

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
srand(time() ^($$ + ($$ <<15))) ;
for ($x=0;$x<10;$x++) {
print rand() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: $$ is your interpreter's pid

Comment: Just to add onto @Arkadly 's response http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: This is really old code. In modern versions of Perl you don't need to call `srand()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`srand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) seeds the random number generator. This is similar to `new Random(seed)` in Java. [`rand()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) is more similar to `Random.nextInt()`. There isn't really any good reason to do this, as it will be called implicitly (and probably with a better seed) the first time `rand()` is used. The stuff inside is basically just trying to get some random-ish data using the PID.

Comment: It's probably very old code, or cargo-culted from very old code. Perl didn't implicitly `srand` with a decent value until about 1996.

Comment: Is it possible to mimic the stuff inside in Java?

Comment: Depends on how precisely you want to mimic it. You probably don't want to implement a new random number generator in Java just to have it generate the same random numbers for each PID.

Comment: @Nick Gilbert, No, it's probably not possible to mimic that line, whose only effect is to potentially lower the randomness of numbers generated afterwards.